# Spring. DB transaction management with spring(hibernate) transaction

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactional

Can you correct me how does it works? Method marked with transaction annotation. Is DB transaction opened and commited both with spring transaction when it is intercepted. Also are all associated resources in DB stays locked while such method is not completed. 
For example in transactional method I got some entities from DB, then multiple times updated or removed some of them. This all is happening in spring transaction and DB transaction happens only at the end of transactional method with necessary locks??? What if the method will hang, for example deadlock, will the locked resources stay locked for others in DB? As I see yes..

```
DB (postgresql) state:

30179 | username  | 00:23:05.688157 | IDLE in transaction
6739  | username  | 00:23:13.02717  | IDLE in transaction                
6748  | username  | 00:23:15.266922 | IDLE in transaction
25595 | username  | 00:23:22.382349 | IDLE in transaction
25595 | username  | 00:23:22.382349 | IDLE in transaction
```

All of them held locks (23, 21, 20, 5, 6). How this could happen? I have not long operations. Only deadlocks :D But this shouldn't happen!! So as I see some transactional method hang, but resources stayed locked, this caused others or next transactions to stop, waiting for locked resources and all system at some moment stopped working...

Answer (score 1):

That all has nothing to do with spring, it are "normal" transactions.

What a transaction exact mean, strongly depends on the [transaction isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) you use.

If "you" enter a method anntoated with `@Transactional`, a tranaction at DB level it started (or at least if the next sql statement is executed). The transaction is commited when you leave that method.

*The `@Transactional` annotation has a parameter to controll what should be done if there is allready a transaction for the current thread*.

Comment: So if I hanged in transactional method, the resources in DB which were locked, stays locked too. Thats very bad. I don't believe in such behavior, there shouldn't be such time-long transactions in DB ..

Comment: I would expect that the DB "detects" the deadlock by an timeout.

Comment: Thats too. But there was deadlock or very long operation in java. Above are DB processes that were in transaction more than 20 minutes. Resources weren't released, transaction too. So I wonder how spring/hibernate transactions cooperate with DB!